# How can I take a group of nested JSON objects and append their data to an editable text field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a group of nested JSON objects which I need to append to a text field.  There are 6 objects and I don't want to hard code 6 text fields.  I have used the .map functionality in the past, but I cannot get it to work in this case.

```
const [questions, setQuestions] = useState('');
const fetchQuestions = async () => {
    setQuestions( await fetch(`/fiscalyears/FY2023/intakes/${params.id}/details/questions`)
                             .then((response) => response.json())
    );
};

useEffect(() => {
    fetchQuestions();
}, []);
```

In side my return statement:

```
{questions?.map((row) => (
    <TextField
        className="text-field"
        value={row?.Value || ''}
        variant="outlined"
        margin="normal"
        label={row['FieldName']}
    />
))}
```

Here is a shortened version of my JSON:

```
{
  "Consulting": [
    {
      "Question": null,
      "Response": null
    }
  ],
  "FED": [
    {
      "Question": "1. Is there any impact to the region applications?",
      "Response": "No"
    },
    {
      "Question": "2. If number 1 is \"Yes\", then are any of the below applications being 
       impacted?",
      "Response": "No"
    },
    {
      "Question": "3. Are you changing data structure? \r\n",
      "Response": null
    }
  ],
  "IPE": [
    {
      "Question": "1. Do you need compute (servers), storage, databases, and/or platform capacity for your effort?",
      "Response": "Yes"
    },
    {
      "Question": "2. If yes, please describe:",
      "Response": "I need servers"
    },
    {
      "Question": "3. Do you need Database Services?\r\n",
      "Response": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map method only for arrays.
For iterate through object, you can use

```
Object.keys(questions).map(function(key, index) {
  //do something here
})
```

Otherwise you can use a for cycle but i dislike it

```
for (var key in questions) {
  if (questions.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    // use questions[key]
  }
}
```

Comment: ```{Object.keys(questions).map(function (key, index) {<TextField className="text-field" variant="outlined" margin="normal" label="Label" />;})}```  This is what I have now, but there is nothing being rendered.  Also, how would I structure an onChange to be able to edit the response field in the Consulting nested object?